# How to package python application as a service?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, debian, apt

I am very new to python and this is my first application that I am trying to deploy. I have below structure in my source-code

```
     - __init__.py
     - myapp.py
     - myapp_config.json
```

myapp.py is importing multiple non-standard python packages.

My end goal here is to install this application in remote host and change the configuration file(myapp_config.json) and start the script(preferred one is 'service start myapp' or even ./myapp.py should work)
Options that I thought about so far:

1. Try creating a python egg/wheel but below are challenges I face

   1. How to package with all the dependency?
   2. Even if I package them with all dependencies is there a way to install these dependencies in universal path and untar myapp.py in current directory ?
   3. How will you make service out of this? Because I think we need to copy some myapp.service file to /etc/ directory to make it as service. Can we do this with python egg/wheel ?
2. Instead of bundling all the dependencies have them download on remote end host and install it. But what if the remote host doesn't have any internet connectivity ?
3. Create a bin/deb package and execute it as ./. Not sure if this idea makes sense or not ? I have no idea where to start on this and how to bundle and install the dependencies